# Repeated (inifinte) Task in c# MAUI

Tags: c#, timer, task, .net-6.0, maui

This is about .Net6 and MAUI

I do have a *List<>* of *items*. Every x seconds in an infinitive loop I send a request with the *item *as *key*.
With the received message I want to refresh the content of my page.
The page is a normal *ContentPage*.

I am still learning, so I do not want to know, what a be better solutions might be (except if what I think is not possible).

I do not have much at the moment except these methods in my `MainPage.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int count = 0;
    string previousitem = "";

    Caps cap = new Caps(@"c:\tmp\xmldata.xml");

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        

        // Methods also in Class MainPage  
        GetNextItem(cap.ReturnListOfItems());
        FillMaui();
    }
```

Well, I tried so many things with Task, AutoResetEvent and TimeSpan and Timer, that I do not have any running code anymore. Well, except the code above...

I am really stuck now and I'm hoping for some hints.

GetNextItem() loops through all the items, starts again at the beginning when reaching the end of the list and even handles a changing list of items.

FillMaui() just changes atributes of my elements in the MainPage.xaml, for example: `this.ItemName.Text = this.previousitem;`

So, how do I start this inifinitive loop, without blocking my app?

Comment: Set a timer/interval. OnTimerEvent loop through your list and do what you have to do. For non blocking use async/await

Answer (score 0):

You could use a timer and fire the refresh code once per the period you define, rather than having it run continuously which will block your app.

Answer (score 0):

First method, you can use the `RefreshView` to provide the refresh command. [RefreshView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/refreshview?view=net-maui-7.0) is a container control that provides pull to refresh functionality for scrollable content. But the child of a RefreshView must be a scrollable control, such as ScrollView, CollectionView, or ListView.

Second method, you can use the MVVM way to make the List change the item automaticly. I prefer you to use the `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of using the List You can check the [From Data Bindings to MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm).